# Where clause based on number of related rows in Laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

How can I make a `where` clause based on number of related items in one-to-many relationship? For example *"select those Orders which have less than 5 Products"* (assuming Order-Product is one-to-many relationship).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use querying relations from laravel's docs: [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations) (look for "Querying Relationship Existence")

Example (basing on docs):

```
// Retrieve all posts that have less than three comments...
$posts = Post::has('comments', '<', 3)->get();
```